# How do I remap the search button on my Logitech MX400?

Tags: mouse, logitech

I have a logitech MX400 wireless. It has a search button I would like to use for pasting (instead of the extremely sensitive but hard to press scroll wheel). I already remapped other buttons with xbindkeys, and used xev to find the button press code, but this does not work for the search button. using xev and clicking the search button I get the following events

```
FocusOut event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967275 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    atom 0x1d7 (_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY), time 23653064, state PropertyNewValue
```

No ButtonPress events. It seems that the search button is intercepted at a level below the X events. Any ideas? I have ubuntu 12.04. Ubuntu actually sees the click and spawns a search dialog, but there's no trace of a click event in the xev.

**Edit**

I checked the method provided with xmodmap. My `.Xmodmap` now contains the following line

```
keycode 225 = XF86Paste NoSymbol XF86Paste``
```

running `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` now disables the button altogether (or at least, I don't get any result by pressing it). I tried `xmodmap -pke` and it prints out:

`keycode 225 = XF86Paste NoSymbol XF86Paste NoSymbol XF86Paste`

Strange enough. All the other entries are similarly formatted. I am close to the solution, but there's still something weird.

**Edit 2**

I tried to run xinput (never heard of this command. amazing stuff). There are two entries for Logitech. Here is the output of listing each of them (id 9 and 10)

```
Logitech USB Receiver                       id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 7 classes:
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 24
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" "Button Side" "Button Extra" "Button Forward" "Button Back" "Button Task" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown"
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Wheel
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Rel Vert Wheel
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 1.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 3
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: -1.000000
          flags: 0x2 ( preferred )


Logitech USB Receiver                       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 6 classes:
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 7
        Button labels: "Button 0" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right"
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Wheel
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 1.000000
          flags: 0x0
```

Testing device 9 does not do anything with the button. Testing device 10 instead works, and this is the output as I click

```
$ xinput test 10
key press   225 
key release 225 
key press   225 
key release 225 
key press   225 
key release 225
```

So it appears that the mouse acts as a keyboard in this regard, but for some reason, xmodmap does not do anything when it receives key 225.

** Edit **

I can confirm that adding `keycode 225 = a` prints an `a` every time I click the button. So the problem seems to be related to how XF86Paste is actually handled. I am sending it, but it's not pasting.

Comment: You have `xbindkeys` set to run when you startup right?   Can you disable it and try again?

Comment: @iSeth: killed xbindkeys. Tried again, same result.

Comment: Open a terminal and run `tail -f /var/log/dmesg` then try pressing the button.  Do you get any output referring to keys/buttons?

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought you wanted to remap the search button you can find on some multimedia keyboards. Totally failed. My previous answers only work for keyboards.

Comment: Before posting another nonsense answer... find out the input id of your mouse with `xinput list` then find out the button code of your search key with `xinput test <MOUSE ID>`. Does this work?

Comment: In this case, try my answer that uses `xdotool` to emulate the key presses. Regarding the xmodmap way...  I'm sorry but I really can't tell why this answer doesn't work, perhaps a bug? Someone that knows what goes wrong here, please tell us!

Comment: @mrcktz: updated again

Comment: By the way, test in gedit or something because testing XF86Paste in a terminal does not work!

Comment: @GerhardBurger: unfortunately it's where I need this functionality the most, since I work with vim and terminals all the time

Comment: There seems to be a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/683694) that lets `xev` show the XF86Paste/XF86Copy events, but nothing happens. That means that you have to use the key combination CTRL+v for pasting. Xmodmap maps the buttons 1:1, but you can use the keyboard shortcuts settings to trigger the execution of an command on key press (see my answer).

Comment: @StefanoBorini Oke fixed, it will now send a middle mouse button which will paste in a terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simulate keyboard events I suggest you the great tool [xdotool [image: Install xdotool]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xdotool).

**1. Install `xdotool`** via terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

or use  the [Software Center [image: Install xdotool]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xdotool).

**2. Create a script** that uses xdotool to emulate the key down events of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>v</kbd>. In the terminal:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin  
gedit ~/bin/fakepaste
```

Copy the following content into the editor window that opened up. After copying the code save, then close it:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/xdotool key CTRL+V  
EOF
```

Now make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/fakepaste
```

**3. Log out** and log in to reload your [PATH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

**4. Create the custom shortcut**

Go to `System Settings`, then go to `Keyboard`, then `Shortcuts`.

Press the `+` button at the bottom of the dialog. Provide a name for the shortcut you're about to create and for the command fill in: `fakepaste`. Press `OK`.

Next to your new shortcut you will see `disabled`. Click on that text and then press the key you want to be assigned to your keyboard emulation.

You should now be able to use your search key for pasting!

Comment: I don't see how this will help on a mouse button, it changes _keyboard_ shortcuts.

Comment: @iSeth: The point is that it turned out that the logitech mouse is both a keyboard and a mouse. It's a mouse for everything _except_ for the search button, where it acts like a keyboard

Answer (score 2):

### xbindkeys solution with xdotool

For this solution you will need `xbindkeys` and `xdotool`

**Kill xbindkeys and dump your button configuration**

```
killall xbindkeys
```

and

```
xbindkeys --defaults >> ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

**Add your new bindings**

Now you can modify this file to add custom bindings, these have the form

```
"<command>"
  <key combination>
```

so if you add

```
"gedit"
  m:0x0 +b:4
```

you will open `gedit` every time you scroll up.

So now you can try one of the following, pick the one that works best for you. In all case `xdotool click 2` will  be emulated, this is the middle mouse button press, and this will paste both in- and outside terminals.

1. *intercept the 225 from your mouse*:

   ```
   "xdotool click 2"
     m:0x0 +b:225
   ```
2. *intercept keycode 225 in general*:

   ```
   "xdotool click 2"
     c:225
   ```
3. *replace all `XF86Search` events* (revert your mouse settings to the original settings first, so that you get the `XF86Search` back):

   ```
   "xdotool click 2"
     XF86Search
   ```

**Start xbindkeys and test**

Run

```
xbindkeys
```

and see if it works.

Comment: I want to let you know that I think you both deserve the bounty as you helped me greatly. I still don't know if your solutions work, I will test them tomorrow, but the bounty is expiring and I don't want it to go to waste. As soon as I have enough points, I will grant you the same bounty. Thanks

Comment: Oke, thanks (although I don't know if that is possible). Glad to be of help ;)

Comment: uhm... you are right. I can only award one here. Don't worry, As soon as I have enough rep, I'll grant on one of your other answers.

Comment: No,no, don't bother. I'm quite alright ;)